# Searching sentences in PDF using Lucene phrase query and PDFBOX

Tags: lucene

I have used the following code for searching text in pdf. It is working fine with single word. But for sentences as mentioned in the code, it is showing that it is not present even if the text is present in the document. can any one help me in resolving this?

```
          Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);

            // Store the index in memory:               
            Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
            // To store an index on disk, use this instead:
            //Directory directory = FSDirectory.open("/tmp/testindex");
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, analyzer);
            IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            Document doc = new Document();
            PDDocument document = null;
                try {
                    document = PDDocument.load(strFilepath);
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception Occured while Loading the document: " + ex);
                }
                int i =1;
                String name = null;           
              String output=new PDFTextStripper().getText(document); 
            //String text = "This is the text to be indexed";
            doc.add(new Field("contents", output, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
            iwriter.addDocument(doc);
            iwriter.close();
            // Now search the index
            DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
            IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
            // Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "contents", analyzer);

            String sentence = "Following are the";
            PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
            String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
               query.add(new Term("contents", word));
            }
            ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
            if(hits.length>0){
                System.out.println("Searched text existed in the PDF.");
            }
            ireader.close();
            directory.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the query parser to create a query from your sentence instead of creating your phrasequery by yourself. your self created query contains the term "Following" which is not indexed since the standard analyzer will lowercase it during indexing so only "following" is indexed.

Comment: I used queryparser. But still the query is not taking the full sentence. instead it is taking the first word and showing that it is not existed. I used the follwing code for queryparser.

Comment: QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT,"contents", analyzer);

          queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
          queryParser.setPhraseSlop(0);
          Query query=queryParser.createPhraseQuery("contents",sentence);
          ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;

Comment: the standardanalyzer filters out stop words, so your query becomes only contents:following anyway. that really means that the word following doesn't exist in your pdf text. can you print out the string 'output'? i'm sure there is no "following" in it.

Comment: Please suggest which analyzer i have to use, to get the complete sentence in the query. Also is there any possibility that I can do it with the help of standard analyzer?

Comment: yes, you provide an empty collection of stopwords in the constructor of standardanalyzer. then you won't have stopwords. BUT: i think your problem is not the analyzer, it's the content of you pdf.